# Why are Primula and Daisy perceived to be the same?

Tags: fall-or-dodge-in-hell

In *Fall, or Dodge in Hell* it appears that the bitspace character of Sophia is reincarnated as both Primula and Daisy. Now both primula and daisy are kinds of common flowers, but they are by no means the same or even similar types of flowers (the most well-known primula is *primula vulgaris*, which is the primrose).

So why does the narrative make an association between these names? Is Neal demonstrating rare ignorance (or disregarding reality to make a plot point) or is there some other explanation?